# Parsing char array in C++

Tags: c++, http, parsing

I'm coding a httpserver and I'm stuck at parsing GET requests.
How would I parse a char buffer with something like

> GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1

So that I only get the path and file extension but ignore the other parts?

Comment: `std::string` & `std::string::substr`

Comment: How would I use substr to get that certain portion? I can set a start value but the end part is never certain.

Comment: Have you read the specs? You can find them here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1 and you'll see what are the parts of the request line and how they're delimited...

Comment: the HTTP1.1 protocol requires the browser to include a hostname and the hostname wont always be the same sadly.

Comment: Without having set out to be nasty, if you can't parse this string perhaps an HTTP server is not the best project for you at this stage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say specifically say what sort of storage this string is in - simple char* or some string class.

So, in general, you could either do it the rather simple and dirty way, by splitting the string on the space character, and taking the second or middle section.  Or, a better approach would be to get familiar with Regular Expressions.  C++ has several regex libraries - [Boost](http://www.boost.org/libs/regex/index.html) is well regarded.

Comment: It is stored in a char array with the size of 2042 bytes. Is there any simple way to do this without using a library?

Comment: Yes, you could iterate through the char array, and only pull out characters between the first and second space into a second array.  I would recommend using regex's however - it would then just become a call to match the input string against a pattern - and the library does all the hard work.

Comment: You need to be careful with URL encoding too - how are spaces encoded in this string, '%20' or similar?

Comment: I looked at the boost library earlier but it said I would need to compile the regex part itself to be able to use it. I'm not entirely sure how to do this. Would you know how to do this Visual C++ 2010?

Comment: You can't put spaces and some other characters in URLs, so your conversion from the URL to the file (or resource) to load will need to take that into account.  Many file systems allow spaces in filenames.

Comment: @Kraffs : VC++ 2010 comes with an implementation of C++0x's regex library, built-in -- see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx) for docs. Alternatively, you could use [Boost.Xpressive](http://www.boost.org/libs/xpressive/index.html), which is header-only (no building/linking required) unlike Boost.Regex.

Comment: Thank you! That will do it I think.

Comment: .. or the solution could be as simple as strtok(), splitting strings since C90

Comment: strtok is the devil's function.